# XSLT interpret cdata and write to file

Tags: file, xslt, cdata

I have a situation like this:

```
<List>
     <Entry>
     <![CDATA[......]]>
     </Entry>
     <Entry>
     <![CDATA[......]]>
     </Entry>
     ...
</List>
```

CDATA sections contain encoded bytes. Each entry's cdata has a control word as the first word, that describes what length of the data will go into a file and how much to seek into that file. For example:
00060000abcdef
will imply a file that contains "abcdef" and of length 6 seeking at 0. The output should be a file that contains abcdef.

Is XSLT the right choice to interpret CDATA in a certain way and write to a file?

1. I can think of using redirect:write as in Xalan
2. Use some sort of custom XSLT function that will break into a parser handler to handle this:

   ```
   <xsl:MyFunc></xsl:MyFunc>
   ```
3. Is there a way to write custom XSLT functions as tags using for, if etc.?

Editing after Dimitre Novatchev's feedback:

Thank you for the response! I hope the below clarifies the question. Sorry.

Input XML File:

```
<File>
  <Chunk>
      <Offset>200</Offset>
      <Length>100</Length>
      <Data>
          <![CDATA[data bytes that can be greater than 100 too, but first 100 is valid.]]>
      </Data>
  </Chunk>
  ...
</File>
```

The output should be a html file that has this:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <a href="resulting_file">file</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is XSLT the right choice to interpret CDATA in a certain way and write
>      to a file?

1. **Yes, CDATA is just a (part of a) text node** and is processed as any other text node.
2. **Yes, the XSLT 2.0 `xsl:result-document` instruction** is used to write to (possibly many different) file(s).

> .2. Use some sort of custom XSLT function that will break into a parser
>   handler to handle this:
>
> `<xsl:MyFunc></xsl:MyFunc>`

**Yes, this is done using the standard XSLT 2.0 instruction `xsl:function`**

```
3.Is there a way to write custom XSLT functions as tags using for, if etc.?
```

**This question isn't clear. XSLT has many such instructions, like** `xsl:for-each`, `xsl:if`, `xsl:choose`, `xsl:when`, `xsl:otherwise`, ... etc.

**XPath 2.0 (which is used within XSLT 2.0) xas its own `for`, `if` `then` `else`, `return` clauses**.

Comment: Could you show me how to seek into a file and write to it in XSLT? i.e., the second entry may have data that fills a different (non-contiguous) chunk of the file.

Comment: @foobarometer, An XSLT problem is defined by provideing a complete (but preferrably not long) XML document and the exact wanted result -- also explaining the rules that the transformation must implement. Please, ask a new question and provide these essential constituents of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have edited the question with a clearer example. Sorry.

Comment: I've asked another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445238/xml-xslt-result-document-fseek), if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well for XSLT it doesn't matter whether your XML input has CDATA sections or not, the XSLT data model is a tree of nodes so there will be `Entry` elements with a single child text node containing the text (e.g. with your sample

```
 <Entry>
 <![CDATA[......]]>
 </Entry>
```

an `Entry` element will contain a single text node containing a line break followed by some space characters followed by `......` followed by a line break followed by some space characters).

You can then process the text node's string value with the XSLT and XPath string functions.