# XML XSLT Result-Document fseek

Tags: xslt, document, fseek

Using XSLT transformation I want to convert an XML file, that in turn represents various chunks of another file, into a HTML file with a link to the file that was represented.

Input XML File:

```
<File>
  <Name>foo.jpg<Name>
  <Chunk>
      <Offset>200</Offset>
      <Length>100</Length>
      <Data>
          <![CDATA[data bytes, encoded in base64, can be greater than length 100 too, but first 100 decoded bytes are valid.]]>
      </Data>
  </Chunk>
  <Chunk>
  ...
</File>
```

The output should be a html file that has a valid link to foo.jpg, i.e., there is another implicit output file called "foo.jpg" with data from the cdata sections in the chunks, at their specified offsets.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <a href="http://example.com/images/foo.jpg">file</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438865/xslt-interpret-cdata-and-write-to-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">

  <xsl:document>
        <html>
           <body>
              <a href="http://example.com/images/{Name}">file</a>
           </body>
        </html>
  </xsl:document>

  <xsl:result-document href="file:///c:/temp/delete/{Name}" method="text">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Chunk">
     <xsl:sort select="Offset" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Chunk">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(Data, 1, Length)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (having two chunks):

```
<File>
  <Name>foo.jpg</Name>
  <Chunk>
      <Offset>200</Offset>
      <Length>100</Length>
      <Data>A01234567891234567890234567890134567890124567890123567890123467890123457890123456890123456790123456780123456789</Data>
  </Chunk>
  <Chunk>
      <Offset>1</Offset>
      <Length>200</Length>
      <Data>Z0123456789123456789023456789013456789012456789012356789012346789012345789012345689012345679012345678012345678901234567891234567890234567890134567890124567890123567890123467890123457890123456890123456790123456780123456789</Data>
  </Chunk>
</File>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html>
   <body><a href="http://example.com/images/foo.jpg">file</a></body>
</html>
```

and the created file: `c:\temp\delete\foo.jpg` has the correct, wanted contents:

```
Z0123456789123456789023456789013456789012456789012356789012346789012345789012345689012345679012345678012345678901234567891234567890234567890134567890124567890123567890123467890123457890123456890123456A012345678912345678902345678901345678901245678901235678901234678901234578901234568901234567901234567
```